# Unable to add users using LDIF file in Osixia-OpenLdap image

Tags: docker, kubernetes, ldap, openldap, osixia

I am trying to create an OpenLdap instance using image `osixia/openldap:1.5.0` as a k8s service. Image works really well and the Ldap instance is also worked fine. However, when I'm trying to create users using `user.ldif` file, getting error. I created a configmap nameing `users` and mounted it to the k8s cluster.

**openldap.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: open-ldap-pod
  labels:
    app: open-ldap-pod
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: open-ldap-pod
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: open-ldap-pod
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: open-ldap-pod
        image: osixia/openldap:1.5.0
        args: [ "-c", "/container/tool/run --copy-service" ]
        ports:
        - containerPort: 389
          name: openldap
        volumeMounts:
        - name: users
          mountPath: /container/service/slapd/assets/config/bootstrap/ldif/custom/users.ldif
          subPath: users.ldif
      volumes:
      - name: users
        configMap:
         name: users
         items:
         - key: users.ldif
           path: users.ldif
```

**users.ldif**

```
dn: ou=People,dc=example,dc=org
ou: People
objectClass: organizationalUnit

dn: cn=john,ou=People,dc=example,dc=org
myAttribute1: myAttribute
myAttribute2: myAttribute
sn: john
mail: john@example.org
cn: john
objectClass: personnel

dn: cn=mike,ou=People,dc=example,dc=org
myAttribute1: myAttribute
myAttribute2: myAttribute
sn: mike
mail: mike@example.org
cn: mike
objectClass: personnel
```

**Error Stack:**

```
*** CONTAINER_LOG_LEVEL = 3 (info)
*** Search service in CONTAINER_SERVICE_DIR = /container/service :
*** link /container/service/:ssl-tools/startup.sh to /container/run/startup/:ssl-tools
*** link /container/service/slapd/startup.sh to /container/run/startup/slapd
*** link /container/service/slapd/process.sh to /container/run/process/slapd/run
*** Set environment for startup files
*** Environment files will be proccessed in this order :
Caution: previously defined variables will not be overriden.
/container/environment/99-default/default.startup.yaml
/container/environment/99-default/default.yaml

To see how this files are processed and environment variables values,
run this container with '--loglevel debug'
*** Running '/container/tool/run --copy-service'...
*** CONTAINER_LOG_LEVEL = 3 (info)
*** Copy /container/service to /container/run/service
*** Search service in CONTAINER_SERVICE_DIR = /container/run/service :
*** link /container/run/service/:ssl-tools/startup.sh to /container/run/startup/:ssl-tools
*** failed to link /container/run/service/:ssl-tools/startup.sh to /container/run/startup/:ssl-tools: [Errno 17] File exists: '/container/run/service/:ssl-tools/startup.sh' -> '/container/run/startup/:ssl-tools'
*** link /container/run/service/slapd/startup.sh to /container/run/startup/slapd
*** failed to link /container/run/service/slapd/startup.sh to /container/run/startup/slapd: [Errno 17] File exists: '/container/run/service/slapd/startup.sh' -> '/container/run/startup/slapd'
*** link /container/run/service/slapd/process.sh to /container/run/process/slapd/run
*** directory /container/run/process/slapd already exists
*** failed to link /container/run/service/slapd/process.sh to /container/run/process/slapd/run : [Errno 17] File exists: '/container/run/service/slapd/process.sh' -> '/container/run/process/slapd/run'
*** Set environment for startup files
*** Environment files will be proccessed in this order :
Caution: previously defined variables will not be overriden.
/container/environment/99-default/default.startup.yaml
/container/environment/99-default/default.yaml

To see how this files are processed and environment variables values,
run this container with '--loglevel debug'
*** Running /container/run/startup/:ssl-tools...
*** Running /container/run/startup/slapd...
openldap user and group adjustments
get current openldap uid/gid info inside container
-------------------------------------
openldap GID/UID
-------------------------------------
User uid: 911
User gid: 911
uid/gid changed: false
-------------------------------------
updating file uid/gid ownership
Database and config directory are empty...
Init new ldap server...
  Backing up /etc/ldap/slapd.d in /var/backups/slapd-2.4.50+dfsg-1~bpo10+1... done.
  Creating initial configuration... done.
  Creating LDAP directory... done.
invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel
invoke-rc.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of restart.
Start OpenLDAP...
Waiting for OpenLDAP to start...
Add bootstrap schemas...
config file testing succeeded
Add image bootstrap ldif...
Add custom bootstrap ldif...
*** /container/run/startup/slapd failed with status 68

*** Killing all processes...
*** /container/tool/run failed with status 1

*** Killing all processes...
```

Is there anything that I'm missing here?

Comment: `slapd` startup failed. It has nothing to do with your LDIF. Off topic.

Comment: @user207421 On-topic. It has everything to do with his LDIF. The `slapd` (Standalone LDAP Daemon) failed while and only because of processing his LDIF data.

Comment: @lchristmann It’s off topic because it’s not about computer programming or software development. Processing bad LDIF data does not cause SLAPD shutdowns.

Comment: @user207421 [Seeding a containerized LDAP database with LDIF files](https://github.com/osixia/docker-openldap#seed-ldap-database-with-ldif) is definitely an issue of software development. Thus, `slapd` failures resulting from this are undoubtedly in scope too.

Comment: @user207421 View the logs with debug mode enabled in my answer to see how this caused the `slapd` to shutdown.

Answer (score -1):

#### LDAP Error 68

The LDAP error code **68 LDAP_ALREADY_EXISTS** (which killed your container) indicates

- that an add operation attempted to add an entry that already exists or
- that the modify operation attempted to rename an entry to the name of an entry that already exists.

[source](https://docs.servicenow.com/de-DE/bundle/vancouver-platform-security/page/administer/reference-pages/reference/r_LDAPErrorCodes.html), [similar source](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=codes-ldap-return)

---

Consider adding the two array elements `["--loglevel", "debug"]` to your args. This will **enable the debug mode for the LDAP server** (as written in the [docs of the osixia/openldap container image that you're using](https://github.com/osixia/docker-openldap#debug)).

**Before** I've had the exact same cryptic error message in my own project as you have here:

```
***  ERROR | /container/run/startup/slapd failed with status 68
```

**After** enabling the debug mode, **it actually told me what the problem was**:

```
65537a07 conn=1015 op=1 ADD dn="dc=mycompany,dc=de"
65537a07 conn=1015 op=1 RESULT tag=105 err=68 text=
65537a07 conn=1015 op=2 UNBIND
65537a07 conn=1015 fd=12 closed
***  DEBUG  | 2023-11-14 13:45:43 | ldap_add: Already exists (68)
adding new entry "dc=mycompany,dc=de"
ldap_add: Already exists (68)
adding new entry "dc=mycompany,dc=de"
65537a07 daemon: shutdown requested and initiated.
65537a07 slapd shutdown: waiting for 0 operations/tasks to finish
65537a07 slapd stopped.
***  ERROR  | 2023-11-14 13:45:43 | /container/run/startup/slapd failed with status 68
```

**I tried to add an entity** with the distinguished name `dc=mycompany,dc=de` **that already existed**.

I don't know what the issue is in your case. My mistake was setting the environment variables `LDAP_ORGANISATION=mycompany`, `LDAP_DOMAIN=mycompany.de` and `LDAP_BASE_DN=dc=mycompany,dc=de` to my container (which creates this root entity automatically at the start), so when [seeding with my LDIF file](https://github.com/osixia/docker-openldap#seed-ldap-database-with-ldif), the entity already existed and I got a fatal error trying to add it a second time.

Comment: This is not a fatal error.

Comment: @user207421 A [fatal error](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatal_exception_error) is an error that causes a program to abort. This is exactly what happens here. The container exits with failure state, all processes are killed. It's dead, not running anymore.